# History is written by the wieners

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, jokes

I read the following joke

> The Hotdog-bun Boy came home from school one day. His mother looked at him and said, “You look so unhappy. Did something go wrong in school today?”
>   “Yes,” he answered. “I hate history class.”
>   “Why is that?” asked the Hotdog-bun Boy’s mother.
>   “Because we read and read, and we listen to the teacher talk, and we have to memorize so many facts, but we never learn anything about Hotdog buns.”
>   “Now son,” said the mother, “how many times do I have to tell you? History is written by the wieners.”

Reference to "History is written by the wieners."

Does wiener is scene sarcasm and mean penis here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although penises are sometimes jocularly called 'wieners', sometimes a sausage is just a sausage. A 'wiener' is a type of sausage, which, in a bun, forms a snack called a 'hot dog'. In this case 'wieners' is used as a pun on 'winners'. "History is written by the winners" is a well known saying.